# R - Iterating xpathApply issue

Tags: r, xml

this is my first post on SE but I use it often!

I have been having a really hard time trying to extract information from PMC XML files using R.

I have been trying to replicate [this](https://github.com/ropensci/rentrez/issues/98) code but find that rather than iterating through the article set and extracting items once per article, the multiple_papers function returns the whole list for each article (in this example there are 6 articles and the list is printed 36 times).

[Sample XML File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ipqdw6vy0pw5mdr/PMC_SE_Examp.xml?dl=0)

```
library(XML)

SearchResults <- xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse('PMC_SE_Examp.xml', useInternal=TRUE))

parse_title <- function(paper){
    print (xpathApply(paper, '//title-group/article-title', xmlValue))
}

parse_multiple_papers <-function(papers){
    thisPaper <- xpathApply(papers, "//pmc-articleset/*", parse_title)
}


x <- parse_multiple_papers(SearchResults)
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening and wondered if anyone could shed some light on this for me? Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a few hours retracing my steps and consulting the original code, I have now managed to get the behaviour I was looking for.  My aim was to extract the author, title, PMID and Abstract from each paper within a set.  The following code does that. I would greatly welcome any feedback.

```
SearchResults<- xmlRoot(xmlParse('PMC_SE_Examp.xml')) #load file and set root

parse_author <- function(author){ #lists separate names. Not sure how to deal with multiple names yet so I used the first 
  fn  <- xmlValue(author[["given-names"]])
  ln  <- xmlValue(author[["surname"]])
  if (is.null(list(forname=fn, lastname=ln))){
    list(forname=NA, lastname=NA)}

  else{list(forname=fn, lastname=ln)}
}


parse_paper <- function(paper){
  author_info <- xpathApply(paper, ".//contrib-group/contrib/name", parse_author)
  title_text <- unlist(xpathApply(paper, ".//title-group/article-title", xmlValue))
  if(is.null(title_text)){title_text=NA} #for incomplete entries
  abstract_text <- unlist(xpathApply(paper, ".//abstract", xmlValue))
  if(is.null(abstract_text)){abstract_text=NA}
  pmid <-xpathSApply(paper, ".//article-meta/article-id[@pub-id-type = 'pmid']", xmlValue)
  if(is.null(pmid)){pmid=NA} #in the original, bind.data.frame is used - doesn't work here, so I create the data frame first and then rbind it
  dat <- data.frame(pid = pmid,aut=author_info[1],tit=title_text,ab=abstract_text)
  res <- rbind(dat)
  res
}

parse_multiple_papers <- function(papers){
 res <- xpathApply(papers, "/pmc-articleset/*", parse_paper)
 do.call(rbind.data.frame, res)
}

z <- parse_multiple_papers(SearchResults)
write.csv(z,"datafile.csv")
```